# Problems properly closing {{}} on a blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble getting the record id encrypted in the url. The error is `Unclosed '(' does not match '}'`.

```
action="{{ url("delete/$hxh->{{Crypt::encrypt('id')}}") }}"
href="{{ url("update/$hxh->{{Crypt::encrypt('id')}}") }}"
```

How do I correctly resolve this in blade.

Comment: You're already in one set of braces, so you don't need them again, and it's breaking the syntax. Use concatenation instead. Though even with concatenation, it's not going to be right, because you're trying to access the property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting in your question shows the issue.
You need to escape your quotes:

```php
action="{{ url(\"delete/$hxh->{{Crypt::encrypt('id')}}\") }}"
ref="{{ url(\"update/$hxh->{{Crypt::encrypt('id')}}\") }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
action="{{ url("delete/".encrypt($hxh->id)) }}"
href="{{ url("update/".encrypt($hxh->id)) }}"
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.